# Error Validations using Reactive Driven Forms angular 11

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms, angular11

Perhaps an Experienced Full Stack Developer can help regarding this - (Not an issue, more research and Development) I have a task where I have to write validations on our new angular 11 platform, they want it to be reactive driven validations, which is fine, my main issue is, Lets say there is a XML File in our DB and that xml contains all the Business Rules validations,  How do I go about calling the XML from the DB into my angular Component to match those values, and if it does match the validation it should output an error.. I understand Template Driven But Reactive Driven while calling an xml file trying to match to those values, thats where I am stuck.. My only guess is writing a service calling that xml convert it to JSON OBJ etc. Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the best option you have is to convert you xml to json and then you can create your `reactive forms` dynamically. I have done something similar like i have json which have all form creation rules(validaitons, feidl names etc)

```
let formFields = [
        {
    name: 'pickupLocations',
    isRequired: true,
    isArray: true,
    nestedFieldsArr: [
      {
        name: 'location',
        isRequired: true
      },
      {
        name: 'lat',
        isRequired: false
      },
      {
        name: 'long',
        isRequired: false
      },
      {
        name: 'locationCode',
        isRequired: false
      },
      {
        name: 'dateTime',
        isRequired: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'deliveryLocations',
    isRequired: true,
    isArray: true,
    nestedFieldsArr: [
      {
        name: 'location',
        isRequired: true
      },
      {
        name: 'lat',
        isRequired: false
      },
      {
        name: 'long',
        isRequired: false
      },
      {
        name: 'locationCode',
        isRequired: false
      },
      {
        name: 'dateTime',
        isRequired: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'bidVehicles',
    isRequired: true,
    isArray: true,
    nestedFieldsArr: [
      {
        name: 'vehicleLoadId',
        isRequired: true
      },
      {
        name: 'numberOfVehicles',
        isRequired: true
      },
      {
        name: 'loadRequirementId',
        isRequired: false,
        defaultValue: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'shipmentWeight',
    isRequired: true
  },
  {
    name: 'budgetMin',
    isRequired: true
  },
]
```

Now i have my function to create forms dynamically like this

```
createForm(fieldsArr: any[]) {
    let formObject = {};
    fieldsArr.forEach(f => {
    formObject[f.name] = f.isArray ? this.fb.array([this.createArrayType(f.nestedFieldsArr)]) : [f.defaultValue ? f.defaultValue : '', f.isRequired ? Validators.required : Validators.nullValidator]
   })
    return this.fb.group(formObject);
}

createArrayType(nestedFieldsArr: any[]) {
  let nestedFormObj = {};
  nestedFieldsArr.forEach(f => {
  nestedFormObj[f.name] = [f.defaultValue ? f.defaultValue : '', f.isRequired ? Validators.required : Validators.nullValidator]
})
  let form = this.fb.group(nestedFormObj);
  return form;
}
```

So in this way i have a `json` which have all `validation` rules, field names and `nested` `array fields`.